# Neovim - Conditional colorschemes

Tags: vim, lua, neovim

## The Objective

I want to set a specific config for a plugin if a certain colorscheme is applied at startup.

## What I tried

```lua
If vim.cmd("colorscheme") == "oxocarbon" then
    print("this is oxocarbon")
else
    print("this isn't oxocarbon")
end
```

## The problem

Everytime I open neovim the theme oxocarbon loads, but the return is "this isn't oxocarbon".

## Minimal config - init.lua

```lua
require('lazy').setup({
{ import = "plugins.core" } -- oxocarbon get installed and loaded
})
require("macros") -- the if statement
```

## Note

After `VimEnter`, when I type the command `:lua vim.cmd("colorscheme")` (or simply `:colorscheme`), it returns "oxocarbon" (Which is the configured theme loaded during `VimEnter`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give you one idea, here it is how I set my colors:

```
local colorscheme = "tokyonight"
-- vim.notify("Selected colorscheme: " .. colorscheme) -- Debugging message

-- local colorscheme = "tokyonight"
local status_ok, _ = pcall(vim.cmd, "colorscheme " .. colorscheme)
if not status_ok then
  vim.notify("colorscheme " .. colorscheme .. " not found!")
  return
end
```